# Doc Testing of a function in python

Tags: python-3.x, doctest

I want to define a function `isPalindrome` and write a doctests

My output:

> True
>   4
>   1
>   1
>   4
>   0

Expected Output:

> True
>   4
>   1
>   1
>   4
>   2

**Code Used:**

```
import math
import random
import re
import inspect

def isPalindrome(x):

    """
    >>> isPalindrome(121)
    True
    >>> isPalindrome(344)
    False
    >>> isPalindrome(-121)
    ValueError: x must be positive integer.
    >>> isPalindrome("hello")
    TypeError: x must be integer.
    """  


    try:
        x = int(x)
        temp=x
        rev=0
        if(x>0):
            while(x>0):
                dig=x%10
                rev=rev*10+dig
                x=x//10
            if(temp==rev):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif(x<0):
            raise TypeError
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("x must be positive integer")
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("x must be an integer")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    x = input()

    if x.isdigit():
        x = int(x)

    res = isPalindrome(x)

    doc = inspect.getdoc(isPalindrome)

    func_count = len(re.findall(r'isPalindrome', doc))
    true_count = len(re.findall(r'True', doc))
    false_count = len(re.findall(r'False', doc))
    pp_count = len(re.findall(r'>>>', doc))
    trace_count = len(re.findall(r'Traceback', doc))

    fptr.write(str(res)+'\n')
    fptr.write(str(func_count)+'\n')
    fptr.write(str(true_count)+'\n')
    fptr.write(str(false_count)+'\n')
    fptr.write(str(pp_count) + '\n')
    fptr.write(str(trace_count) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your doc test doesn't handle exceptions properly, here is corrected test:

```
"""
>>> isPalindrome(121)
True
>>> isPalindrome(344)
False
>>> isPalindrome(-121)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
ValueError: x must be positive integer.
>>> isPalindrome("hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: x must be an integer.
"""
```

Note that I added `Traceback (most recent call last): ...` to cases with exceptions and added `an` to `TypeError: x must be an integer.`